# What is the benefit of a concurrent garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, garbage-collection

1. Does a concurrent garbage collection also suspend all threads in the application other than the one it is running on?
2. Let us consider a desktop application with a user interface. If a concurrent collection is also going to suspend all threads anyway, then there's no point in making it concurrent, right? What is benefit of having a concurrent garbage collection?

Also, [the MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec(v=vs.100).aspx) two contradictions:

a. That it is good to have a concurrent collection enabled for a single-threaded GUI application, for example a desktop application; and

b. That a concurrent garbage collection causes a performance hit.

So, my next question is:

3. Why does the concurrent collection cause a degradation in performance? And finally,
4. What do I do if I want to register for notifications from the garbage collector for my desktop application? According to the MSDN page linked above, it is recommended to use a concurrent collection (the default) for UI applications. But the MSDN also says that [notifications are not supported for concurrent collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687(v=vs.110).aspx); they are only supported for blocking collections.

Comment: Multiple avenues of exploration should be raised as separate questions. Other than that, not sure why this would be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Concurrent garbage collection does not suspend other threads, but thread scheduling code suspends threads, if there are not enough CPU cores.
2. Having a concurrent garbage collection benefit is for UI applications, not blocked UI, a responsive UI.
3. If you don't have enough CPU cores, and if you have lots of threads or applications on the same machine, process scheduling and thread scheduling will decrease performance.
4. Garbage collector notifications are for servers not for desktops.

Comment: Thank you, All the confusion I had was born out of one wrong assumption I had made: that all garbage collections, including concurrent ones, suspend all threads. When that got cleared, that answered all the other questions, as does your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to hamza kılıç's answer:

1. Not suspending the application's threads is what "concurrent" *means*.
2. UI applications *and any other application with real-time requirements.*  (I.e., any application that needs to respond promptly to asynchronous inputs.)
3. ...and also, a concurrent GC has to do a lot of extra work (as compared to a stop-the-world GC) in order to prevent something like this from happening:

   - Variable `v` refers to object `o`, variable `w` is NULL
   - GC thread examines `w`.  Nothing interesting to see here, but...
   - GC thread loses its time slice,
   - Application thread sets `w = v; v = NULL;`
   - GC gets to run again, examines `v`.  Nothing interesting to see here either.
   - GC finishes its sweep, never found a reference to object `o`.
   - GC deletes object `o`,
   - Application thread tries to call `w.fubar(...)`

Google for "tri-color invariant" If you want to learn more about (3)

Comment: Beautiful answer. i especially loved point #3. I will look into "tri-color invariant." Thank you. Even though I know what concurrent means, my confusion was based in my wrong assumption that all garbage collections suspend all threads, and so I couldn't reconcile what a concurrent collection was with that understanding. I'd just not read through the documentation for it. Many thanks for such a beautiful explanation.